# What's the canonical way to join strings in a list?

Tags: common-lisp

I want to convert `("USERID=XYZ" "USERPWD=123")` to `"USERID=XYZ&USERPWD=123"`.  I tried

```
(apply #'concatenate 'string '("USERID=XYZ" "USERPWD=123"))
```

which will return `""USERID=XYZUSERPWD=123"`.

But i do not know how to insert '&'? The following function works but seems a bit complicated.

```
(defun join (list &optional (delim "&"))
    (with-output-to-string (s)
        (when list
            (format s "~A" (first list))
            (dolist (element (rest list))
               (format s "~A~A" delim element)))))
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Use [FORMAT](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_cg.htm).

`~{` and `~}` denote iteration, `~A` denotes aesthetic printing, and `~^` (aka Tilde Circumflex in the docs) denotes printing the , only when something follows it.

```
* (format nil "~{~A~^, ~}" '( 1 2 3 4 ))

"1, 2, 3, 4"
*
```

Comment: This unfortunately does not work in Emacs "elisp". They have a different format function.  Is there any comparable way to do this in Emacs?

Comment: @russ: Probably. Not being an elisp wizard, I went back to basic Lisp... `(defun join-to-str (thing &rest strings)
  (labels
      ((recurser (strings)
                 (cond ((> (length strings) 1)
                        (append (list (car strings)
                                      thing)
                                (recurser (cdr strings))))
                       (t
                        (cons (car strings) nil)))))
    (apply 'concat (recurser strings))))`

Comment: @russ better late than never, if you're concatenating strings: `(mapconcat 'identity '("one" "two") ", ")` but if they aren't strings, you want to change `'identity` to `(lambda (x) (format "%s" x))`

Answer (score 9):

This solution allows us to use `FORMAT` to produce a string and to have a variable delimiter. The aim is not to cons a new *format string* for each call of this function. A good Common Lisp compiler also may want to compile a given fixed *format string* - which is defeated when the *format string* is constructed at runtime. See the macro [`formatter`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_format.htm#formatter).

```
(defun %d (stream &rest args)
  "internal function, writing the dynamic value of the variable
DELIM to the output STREAM. To be called from inside JOIN."
  (declare (ignore args)
           (special delim))
  (princ delim stream))

(defun join (list delim)
  "creates a string, with the elements of list printed and each
element separated by DELIM"
  (declare (special delim))
  (format nil "~{~a~^~/%d/~:*~}" list))
```

Explanation:

```
"~{      iteration start
 ~a      print element
 ~^      exit iteration if no more elements
 ~/%d/   call function %d with one element
 ~:*     move one element backwards
 ~}"     end of iteration command
```

`%d` is just an 'internal' function, which should not be called outside `join`. As a marker for that, it has the `%` prefix.

`~/foo/` is a way to [call a function](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_ced.htm) `foo` from a *format string*.

The variables `delim` are declared special, so that there can be a value for the delimiter transferred into the `%d` function. Since we can't make Lisp call the `%d` function from `FORMAT` with a delimiter argument, we need to get it from somewhere else - here from a dynamic binding introduced by the `join` function.

The only purpose of the function `%d` is to write a delimiter - it ignores the arguments passed by `format` - it only uses the `stream` argument.

Comment: Dear Rainer, is there a reason, why you make the variable name begin with `%`? Is the `(declare (special delim))` kind of a way to make the `delim` variable bind dynamically or so? How does this function exactly work? Why the `%d` function needs those arguments?

Comment: Where one can find anythng about the `~/ /` directive? - I couldn't find about it anything in CLTL ...

Comment: @coredump Thank you! Okay, still learning where to search/gather the information for cl stuff - obviously :D.

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim: you can find `~/` in the Common Lisp Hyperspec, use the master index, non-alphabetic chars: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/X_Mast_9.htm

Comment: @RainerJoswig: Thank you very much! Thank you for the detailed explanation! This is sth I was searching. However, do you have an idea about my `"#\\Tab"` as `"#\Tab"` problem in my question?

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim: which tab problem? Make a separate question. Note that my function does: `(join '(1 2 3 4 5) #\tab)`  -> `"1 2 3 4 5"` - with tab characters between the numbers.

Comment: @Rainer - just right now I see that someone asked exactly the question I want to post (or did post). My question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50647635/nicer-pythonic-join-in-common-lisp?noredirect=1#comment88310300_50647635 and other persons: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23577195/common-lisp-printing-the-tab-character-in-function-format

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172272/discussion-between-gwang-jin-kim-and-rainer-joswig).

Answer (score 6):

[Melpa](https://stable.melpa.org/) hosts the package [s](https://stable.melpa.org/#/s) ("The long lost Emacs string manipulation library"), which provides many simple string utilities, including a string joiner:

```
(require 's)                                                                                                                                                                                          
(s-join ", " (list "a" "b" "c"))                                                                                                                                                                      
"a, b, c"
```

For what it's worth, very thinly under the hood, it's using a couple lisp functions from `fns.c`, namely `mapconcat` and `identity`:

```
(mapconcat 'identity (list "a" "b" "c") ", ")                                                                                                                                                         
"a, b, c"
```

Comment: I note that this question is tagged with `common-lisp`, so this answer is arguably off-topic... that said, it does look useful for those who will undoubtedly also land here when looking for an elisp solution, so... good stuff, just noting for any non-emacs-user common-lisp newbies that this answer does not apply to you.  :)

Answer (score 4):

A bit late to the party, but `reduce` works fine:

```
(reduce (lambda (acc x)
          (if (zerop (length acc))
              x
              (concatenate 'string acc "&" x)))
        (list "name=slappy" "friends=none" "eats=dogpoo")
        :initial-value "")
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming a list of strings and a single character delimiter, the following should work efficiently for frequent invocation on short lists:

```
(defun join (list &optional (delimiter #\&))
  (with-output-to-string (stream)
    (join-to-stream stream list delimiter)))

(defun join-to-stream (stream list &optional (delimiter #\&))
  (destructuring-bind (&optional first &rest rest) list
    (when first
      (write-string first stream)
      (when rest
        (write-char delimiter stream)
        (join-to-stream stream rest delimiter)))))
```

Answer (score 2):

With the newish and simple [str](https://github.com/vindarel/cl-str/) library:

```
(ql:quickload "str")
(str:join "&" '("USERID=XYZ" "USERPWD=123"))
```

It uses format like explained in the other answers:

```
(defun join (separator strings)
" "
(let ((separator (replace-all "~" "~~" separator)))
  (format nil
        (concatenate 'string "~{~a~^" separator "~}")
        strings)))
```

(author of it, to make simple things like this simple).