# Is there a function that joins a list of strings into a delimited string?

Tags: elisp

Is there a function in Emacs Lisp that does the opposite of `split-string`, i.e. joins the elements of a list into string delimited by a given delimiter? In other words, is there a function that given a list, e.g. `("foo" "bar" "baz")`, and a delimiter, e.g. `", "`, returns that list as a string delimited by that delimiter, e.g. `"foo, bar, baz"`.

[Common Lisp seems to have such a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830888/whats-the-canonical-way-to-join-strings-in-a-list) but the function with the same name in Emacs Lisp, [`format`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Formatting-Strings.html), is a wholly different function.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I think you are looking for [mapconcat](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Mapping-Functions.html):

> `mapconcat` applies function to each element of sequence: the results,
>   which must be strings, are concatenated. Between each pair of result
>   strings, `mapconcat` inserts the string separator. Usually separator
>   contains a space or comma or other suitable punctuation.

Comment: [`(mapconcat 'identity '("foo" "bar" "baz") ", ")`](http://www.rhinocerus.net/forum/lang-lisp/576185-emacs-lisps-mapconcat-common-lisp.html#post2300674)

Comment: The example made this answer much more useful.

Comment: default package of emacs 24.5 `24.5/lisp/emacs-lisp/subr-x.el` has the same function as mentioned by @N.N. named `string-join`.

Answer (score 47):

Emacs has `string-join` since 24.4 as part of `subr-x.el`:

```
(eval-when-compile (require 'subr-x))
(string-join '("one" "two" "three") ", ") ; ==> "one, two, three"
```

`subr-x.el` contains also other useful (string manipulation) functions - from the 24.4 release notes:

```
New library subr-x.el for misc helper functions

hash-table-keys
hash-table-values
string-blank-p
string-empty-p
string-join
string-reverse
string-trim-left
string-trim-right
string-trim
string-remove-prefix
string-remove-suffix
```

Comment: That's nice! From where did you get this reference? I couldn't find on the docs.  https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/elisp.html

Comment: `string-join` is part of [subr-x.el](https://emacsredux.com/blog/2014/02/02/a-peek-at-emacs-24-dot-4-new-string-manipulation-functions/).

Answer (score 12):

If you use string manipulation heavily in your Elisp, i recommend you to install a library [`s.el`](https://github.com/magnars/s.el), which has a vast and consistent API for strings. For your task it has a function [`s-join`](https://github.com/magnars/s.el#s-join-separator-strings):

```
(s-join "+" '("abc" "def" "ghi")) ;; => "abc+def+ghi"
(s-join "\n" '("abc" "def" "ghi")) ;; => "abc\ndef\nghi"
```

Answer (score 8):

Depending what you're doing, there may be a better function eg if you're building command line args, use `combine-and-quote-strings` which does the work for you.

```
(combine-and-quote-strings '("foo" "bar" "baz") ", ")
"foo, bar, baz"
```