# Common-Lisp printing the tab character in function format

Tags: tabs, format, common-lisp

I wish to print the tab character with the `format` function. I can achieve this with `~C` and then placing `#\tab` as an argument to format, but this seems a bit verbose as for a newline one can simply place a `~%` in the string.

- What is the most commonly used practise for printing tabs with the `format` function?

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: I suppose, then, you don't want to just put a literal tab into the format string, itself?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no notation for the tab character in `FORMAT`.

There are several choices, but none is really really good.

- use `#\tab` (or a variable set to the character) as the argument, as you mention, is okay for me
- embed a literal tab character in the string. This may break with some editor settings, where the editor replaces tabs with spaces. It's also not directly visible.
- use a function in a format string, which writes a tab character
- use a reader macro to introduce extended string syntax. Probably not bad. Maybe there exists even one. There was a post on comp.lang.lisp with an example.

Comment: For more info, these options are covered here https://groups.google.com/g/comp.lang.lisp/c/Ac_FqxHKdnA