# Format over list: use arguments that aren't in list

Tags: format, common-lisp

Here's a code snippet that I wrote, but doesn't work:

```
(let ((separator "|")
      (text '("Just" "do" "it" "!")))
  (format t "~{~A~A~%~}" text separator))
```

The output should look like:

```
Just|
do|
it|
!|
```

However, it won't work like that - when I'm inside `~{~}`, I don't know how I can add elements from outside the list. I could do this:

`(format t "~{~A|~%~}" text)`

but this does not allow me to use `separator` from variable, and that's what I'm after.

Now I know that I could merge `text` with separator, by adding separator in every even place, but that looks ugly to me. Is there other way to do it in `format`?

Comment: This is almost answered by the accepted answer to http://stackoverflow.com/q/8830888/1281433, except that you want the separator not coded into the string.  The [non-accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9432718/1281433) is more general and could be used here (adjusting to let the delimiter be a string, and not just a character).

Comment: This is absolutely _not_ answered! I want to have separator defined elsewhere, and the whole question is about that - the answer in the question you showed shows how to make separator separate elements instead of getting printed after each element.

Comment: I said it's **almost** answered.  If you didn't need to have the separator defined outside, this would simply be: **(format t "~{~A|~%~}" items)**.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I didn't need it to separate, but to be at the end of each element, and apart from that I already knew how to do what you showed - the exact thing I was missing wasn't there, so the answer wasn't of much use for me, but thanks for the link - somebody might stumble across it and find it useful.

Comment: It's still a separator;  you just don't omit it after the final element.  In your code, you even called it `separator`.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I'm not really that great at providing clear questions. Luckily, I provided code snippet too, which is a bit more unambiguous.

Comment: I wonder if something can be done with ~* (go-to).  It *almost* works, in that could pass in the list (separator items...) and then do an iteration like ~{~A~0@*~} which says "process an element, then go-to element 0, etc.  The problem is that ~@ doesn't just use the element at the given position, but resets the iteration position...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [Tilde Slash](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_ced.htm) format directive, that allows a user-defined function as format specifier. This is just to give you a possible example, many variations on this are possible:

```
CL-USER> (defvar *separator* " ")
*SEPARATOR*
CL-USER> (defun q(stream arg &rest args)
           (declare (ignore args))
           (format stream "~a~a" arg *separator*))
Q
CL-USER> (let ((*separator* "|")
               (text '("Just" "do" "it" "!")))
           (format t "~{~/q/~%~}" text))
Just|
do|
it|
!|
NIL
CL-USER> (let ((*separator* "+++")
               (text '("Just" "do" "it" "!")))
           (format t "~{~/q/~%~}" text))
Just+++
do+++
it+++
!+++
NIL
CL-USER>
```

Comment: Both answers have their downsides, but I guess I prefer this one.

Answer (score 4):

This is a hack:

```
CL-USER 49 > (let ((separator "|")
                   (text '("Just" "do" "it" "!")))
                (format t
                        (concatenate 'string "~{~A" separator "~%~}")
                        text))
Just|
do|
it|
!|
```

Escaping tilde in the separator string:

```
CL-USER 56 > (flet ((fix-tilde (string)
                      (with-output-to-string (s)
                        (loop for c across string
                              when (char= c #\~)
                              do (write-string "~~" s)
                              else do (write-char c s)))))
               (let ((separator (fix-tilde "~a~a"))
                     (text '("Just" "do" "it" "!")))
                 (format t
                         (concatenate 'string "~{~A" separator "~%~}")
                         text)))
Just~a~a
do~a~a
it~a~a
!~a~a
```

Comment: But this won't work if the separator contains any format directives.  E.g., if separator is `"~}"` or `"~A"`, you won't get the right output.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: true. It's a hack. ;-) But it should be fixable by escaping every tilde with another tilde.

Comment: Nice, that's one way of doing it. I hope that someone will come across with something even better though :)

Comment: escaping the tilde, done. Well, could be done with another FORMAT. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Changing the answer from renzo a bit: if we use SPECIAL declarations, we don't need the global variable:

```
(defun %d1 (stream arg &rest args)
  (declare (ignore args)
           (special delim))
  (princ arg stream)
  (princ delim stream))

(defun my-print (list delim)
  (declare (special delim))
  (format nil "~{~/%d1/~%~}" list))
```