# How would I print out a list with spaces in between elements

Tags: common-lisp

So I'm trying to print out a list that looks a little bit something like this `(setq lst (list '- '- '- '- '-))` and in the past I used the print command to print out the whole list, however, when printing the whole list there is parenthesis on each side which I do not want to see. I want to use something like `(format t)` to print every bit of my list and I have something like this set up.

```
(loop for item from 0 to 4
     do (progn
             (format t "~X" (nth item lst))
        )
)
```

This code prints out the  list perfectly fine like this, `-----` but as a mentioned, I want it to print spaces between each element so that it is output like this `- - - - -`. I used the conditional `"~X"` because I looked up how to output spaces with the format command and you are apparently supposed to use `"~X"` but it does not work so if anybody knows how I could put spaces between elements that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: where is this 'conditional' documented? What does it mean 'it does not work'?

Comment: https://www.xspdf.com/resolution/10351055.html

Comment: That's `sprintf`, not `format`.

Comment: In `FORMAT`, `~X` is for printing in hexadecimal: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/22_cbe.htm

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `nth` instead of `for item in lst`?

Comment: That makes sense but what's the conditional to make a space?

Comment: Why not just put a space in the format string? `"~A "`

Comment: that looks like a site of random garbage. Probably better to read actual documentation. http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_c.htm

Comment: There's no conditional space in FORMAT

Comment: Well I simplified down my code for this post but in reality I'm using nested lists so I have nested loops to run them but the code still works the same way.

Comment: You could perhaps implement it using `~[`. See http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/22_cgb.htm

Comment: I tried "~A" but it didn't change anything.

Comment: I tried "~[" but since there was no ] to go with it my computer got confused.

Comment: Imma read the article you sent real quick hold on.

Comment: Alright I'm adequately confused by this http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/22_cgb.htm could you explain your idea?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830888/whats-the-canonical-way-to-join-strings-in-a-list/41091118#41091118

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use the features provided by [`format`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/22_c.htm):

```
CL-USER> (defvar *my-list* '(- - - -))
*MY-LIST*
CL-USER> (format nil "~{~A~^  ~}" *my-list*)
"-  -  -  -"
CL-USER> (format t "~{~A~^  ~}" *my-list*)
-  -  -  -
NIL
```

Here the first call to `format` outputs to a string to show where the spaces are placed. `~{` is an iteration directive that takes a list as its argument. The directives between the opening `~{` and closing `~}` are used repeatedly as a format string for the elements of the input list. The `~^` directive causes an early escape from the iteration context when there are no more arguments; this prevents a trailing space from being added.

The second call to `format` just outputs to `*standard-output*`.

Comment: The reason why I didn't do it like this is because I need to be able to index each item in a list and running functions on a string is something that I do not know how to do.

Comment: Well, now I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish. Why do you need to index each list element? [Why are you using nested lists "in reality"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68240118/how-would-i-print-out-a-list-with-spaces-in-between-elements/68240236#comment120605251_68240118) I answered wrt "_how would I print a list with spaces between elements_," but the new requirements are not clear; a good [MCVE] would help here.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your update, that you posted in the answers to your own post:

- First of all, you should edit your post to show us that you found a solution, rather than having us look through all the answers to see how much progress you made on your initial problem.
- As it was already mentioned in another answer, you can iterate through the elements of a list using `format` built-in syntax with `~{~}` and `~^` (see the documentation !)
- In your own solution, when you iterate over the list using `loop`, you can put a space at the end of the format string rather than calling `format` twice ...
- You can use `loop for <elt> in <list>` rather than iterating with the indices, and calling `nth` at each step - which is slower, and also more verbose.
- The `loop ... do <stuff>` already wraps the `<stuff>` in what we call an implicit progn, i.e. you do not need to wrap yourself all your instructions in a `progn`, the `loop` macro does that for you.
- There also exists the macro `dolist`, which is (arguably) simpler to use in those case when you simply want to iterate over a list.

To be fair, it looks like you are a Common Lisp beginner. In this case, I suggest you read the excellent [Practical Common Lisp](https://gigamonkeys.com/book/) book, which covers in details the loop macro, the format function, and a lot of basic principles. It is available for free online, and is often recommended to beginners, for good reasons !

Answer (score -3):

Ok I came up with an ingenius solution to my problem which I definitely should've seen before.

```
(loop for item from 0 to 4
     do (progn
             (format t "~X" (nth item lst))
             (format t " ")
        )
)
```

I didn't realize I could print a space like that but it works perfectly fine. Sorry for wasting you all's time but hopefully someone else can see this if they are having a brain fart like me and thanks to everyone who tried to help.